# Selenium scraping; trying to add classes to a dataframe

Tags: python, selenium, dataframe, missing-data

I am scraping the job title, company, location and summary of jobs posted on Indeed. As there is data missing in the company category, I need help in figuring out how to deal with this missing information.

I am able to obtain all the relevant information by using:

```
company = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("company")
```

etc.

Next, I go through the text values of the drivers and append them to a list:

```
joblist = []
for i in range(len(jobs)):
    joblist.append(jobs[i].text)
```

Finally, I  add this information into a pandas DataFrame:

```
df["Job Title"] = joblist
```

etc.

What I have found now, is that some job postings do *not* have their company name listed in its appropriate category, but rather put the company name in the job title. When a value of company is missing, or empty for a certain posting, how can I add an empty slot, corresponding to the correct job posting, to the companies list/dataframe? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide the piece of HTML code where company name is present and where it is not present? Maybe you could select element by some other selector which would always work. Point here is that you need to include the listings, even when company is not specified, which means, that you have to obtain them with some other selector

Comment: shorter and without `range(len())` - `joblist = [x.text for x in jobs]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404147/how-to-scrape-not-well-structured-html-tables-with-beautifulsoup-in-python this might help you.

Comment: @furas thank you for the suggestion. Your method gives the same final result though, where the companies list is not the same size as the jobs list, and the companies are out of order. Essentially I would like to add a NaN to where the company category is missing.

Comment: it is only comment to code - not solution. Place for solutions is below - as `Answer`

Comment: as others said - find element in HTML which keep all data for one company - ie some `<div>` which groups all information for one company - and then search inside this element all elements for one company. If you find name then you keep it in `one_company["name"] = name`, and if you don't find (or catch error using `try/except`) then you set `one_company["name"] = 'NAN'`. It is not good idea to search all names separatelly and other information separatelly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use wrong method - you search separatelly all companies, separatelly all titles, etc.

```
company = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("company")
summary = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("summary")
location = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("location")
title = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title")
```

but you should search object which keeps all information for single offer and later search in this offer

```
all_offers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("info")

joblist = []

for offer in all_offers:
    # uses `offer` instead `driver` to search only in this one offer
    # uses `element` instead of `elements` to search only one value

    try:
        company = offer.find_element_by_class_name("company").text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        #print('[Exception] company:', ex)
        company = 'NAN'

    summary = offer.find_element_by_class_name("summary").text.strip()
    location = offer.find_element_by_class_name("location").text.strip()
    title = offer.find_element_by_class_name("title").text.strip()

    joblist.append([company, summary, location, title])
```

---

**EDIT:** Minimal working example with https://books.toscrape.com which was created to learn scraping.

There is no class `other` on this page so it will add `NAN` to all rows of data

```
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://books.toscrape.com')

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('product_pod')

data = []

for item in all_items:
    try:
        name = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3/a').get_attribute('title')
    except Exception as ex:
        #print('[Exception] name:', ex)
        name = ''

    try:    
        price = item.find_element_by_class_name('price_color').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        #print('[Exception] price:', ex)
        price = ''

    try:    
        other = item.find_element_by_class_name('other').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        #print('[Exception] other:', ex)
        other = 'NAN'

    data.append([name, price, other])

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

Result:

```
['A Light in the Attic', '£51.77', 'NAN']
['Tipping the Velvet', '£53.74', 'NAN']
['Soumission', '£50.10', 'NAN']
['Sharp Objects', '£47.82', 'NAN']
['Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind', '£54.23', 'NAN']
['The Requiem Red', '£22.65', 'NAN']
['The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job', '£33.34', 'NAN']
['The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull', '£17.93', 'NAN']
['The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics', '£22.60', 'NAN']
['The Black Maria', '£52.15', 'NAN']
['Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)', '£13.99', 'NAN']
["Shakespeare's Sonnets", '£20.66', 'NAN']
['Set Me Free', '£17.46', 'NAN']
["Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)", '£52.29', 'NAN']
['Rip it Up and Start Again', '£35.02', 'NAN']
['Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991', '£57.25', 'NAN']
['Olio', '£23.88', 'NAN']
['Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849', '£37.59', 'NAN']
['Libertarianism for Beginners', '£51.33', 'NAN']
["It's Only the Himalayas", '£45.17', 'NAN']
```

Comment: Thank you, this certainly helped a lot. I dug down deeper and found the object which contained all information on the offer as you suggested.